# error al ejecutar npm run deploy

Tags: git, github, github-pages

Antes tenia el sistema operativo de linux pero cambie a windows por ciertas razones, entonces tenia un proyecto en github en el cual usaba con normalidad gh-pages para mandar a produccion mi proyecto de vue con el comando npm run deploy claro que antes hago un npm run build, el caso es que ahora al correr este comando recibo este error..

> retratosvite@0.0.0 deploy
> gh-pages -d dist

Error: Failed to get remote.origin.url (task must either be run in a git repository with a configured origin remote or must be configured with the "repo" option).
at D:\LIMBERT\proyectos_web\vue\gallery_vuejs\node_modules\gh-pages\lib\git.js:214:13
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

he probado borrar el proyecto, volver a clonarlo, borrar node_module, hacer npm install,añadir el repositoio..pero sigo teniendo el mismo error, agradezco su ayuda de antemano